# does threading.join() block the thread that's called it?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

Based on https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html :

> join() waits until the thread terminates. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called terminates

Now I'm a bit confused. Consider the code below:

```
import threading

def count(start, end):
    for i in range(start, end):
        print(i)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=count, args=[10, 20])
t2 = threading.Thread(target=count, args=[30, 40])

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Output:

```
10
11
12
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

t1.join() is called in the main thread. So I consider the main thread blocked and t2.join() not called.
In this situation I expect not to see any number in the range given to t2 before any number in the range given to t1.
So how come 30 is printed before 19?

Comment: `t2.join()` blocks the calling thread. `t2` itself is still running.

Comment: The main thread is blocked, but the other threads are not. `t1` and `t2` are still running at the same time while the main thread waits.

Comment: "I expect to not see numbers from range given to t2" implies "t2 is not running". Which is wrong. I've pointed that out to you in my comment. And since you're wrong & t2 is still running you will see numbers from t2 (print has nothing to do with the state of the main thread).  And yes I did read the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program starts the two threads before waiting for t1 and t2 to finish, that is why you have `30` before `19` in your console. 
While the programs wait for t1 to finish, t2 is still running and printing to the console.
If for any reason you want to use multithreading and have `t2` waiting for `t1` to finish before starting, you can use the following code :

```py
import threading
import time # Useful for adding some delay in order to visualize what is happening

def count(start, end):
    for i in range(start, end):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(500) # Add some delay to see clearly what is happening

t1 = threading.Thread(target=count, args=[10, 20])
t2 = threading.Thread(target=count, args=[30, 40])

# This starts the two threads and wait for bot of them to finish
#t1.start()
#t2.start()
#
#t1.join()
#t2.join()
#

# This starts one thread and wait for it to finish before starting the other
t1.start()
t1.join() # We wait for t1 to finish

t2.start() # Then we start the second thread (t2)
t2.join()
```

NB : You can't start the same thread 2 times so make sure to comment/delete my part if you want to test the code with the 2 threads running at the same time.

EDIT : By program I mean main thread